# Run function every 5s inside loop running every second

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I need to run my function `MyFunc()` every five seconds using the parameters in the code (i.e. minimum code changes).

There are two parameters in the code: `ts` and `std::chrono::system_clock::now()`

What do I write in `condition` so that I can run my function at the interval?

```
auto ts = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);

do {
    // 1s timer
    if ( ts <= std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {

        // ... doing some work

        // here I need to start MyFunc() every 5s
        if (condition) {
            MyFunc();
        }

        ts += std::chrono::seconds(1);
    }

} while (isWork);
```

Comment: `if( lastTimeTheFunctionWasRun + 5s < std::chrono::steady_clock::now() )` This is literally "if last time my function was run was more than 5 seconds ago". Of course it does not guarantee that the intervals between function will be exactly 5s. But to achieve high ratio accuracy you need more than just sleeps and system clock.

Comment: Keep track of when it was last run. If `now() - lastRun >= 5`, then call your function.

Comment: May be using https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async? Call asynchronously a function that sleeps for 5s and then which calls asynchronously your function and repeat.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Yes but then without sleep, but condition variable wait_for to have more responsive shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in my mind is to check whether the time passed is greater than 5 seconds. You could do something similar to this, where there is a separate variable to keep track of 5 seconds after the last time that the function was run:

```cpp
auto ts = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(1);
auto fiveseconds = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(5);

do {
    // 1s timer
    if ( ts <= std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {

        // ... doing some work

        // here I need to start MyFunc() every 5s
        if (fiveseconds <= std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {
            MyFunc();
            fiveseconds = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(5);
        }

        ts += std::chrono::seconds(1);
    }

} while (isWork);
```

Note that this may not run it *exactly* every five seconds, just about when it runs the once-a-second loop, and then checks if it has been over five seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it. I don't use sleep because that could delay shutdown a lot. Instead I use a condition variable to wait at most 5 seconds to check
if a stop condition is triggered, but returns immediately if the stop condition is triggered. This make reaction to your stopping much more responsive.

By using std::async the main thread keeps free for other things if needed. Also this will not be a busy wait loop (low CPU usage) to check if time has passed.

Live demo here (with 1s loop time) https://onlinegdb.com/qYA_IBqFQ

Some background material:

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/
https://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-9-stdasync-tutorial-example/
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable (despite its name it is more of an interthread signal then a variable)

```
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    bool keep_running{ true };              // a flag indicating if you want to keep processing
    std::condition_variable signal;         // a signal between two threads that (maybe) keep_running has changed value
    std::mutex mtx;                         // a mutex to use with flag/signal. (mutexes are often needed when more then 1 thread is involved)

    std::cout << "press return to stop\n";

    char output_char = 'x';

    // launch a lambda function in a thread
    // pass the boolean keep running
    // [&] captures : output_char, mtx, signal and keep_running by reference
    // making them available in the background thread.
    // (Make sure these variables 'live' longer then the duration of the thread
    // thats why the future.get() later is important).
    auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]
        {
            while (keep_running)
            {
                std::cout << output_char;   // show we are looping

                // get a lock, this is needed for safe waiting on the signal
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>  lock{ mtx };

                // I tend to never use sleep, but use a condition variable to
                // be able to respond faster
                // wait_for waits for 5s OR until keep_runnning is false
                signal.wait_for(lock, 5s, [&] { return !keep_running; }); 
            }
        });

    auto c = getchar();
    std::cout << "stopping\n";

    // update keep_running and condition variable in a lock too
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ mtx };
        keep_running = false;
        signal.notify_one();
    }

    future.get(); // wait for thread to have stopped.
    std::cout << "stopped\n";

    return 0;
}
```